# Maven – No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to learn now how to use Apache Maven. I write this code in Eclipse and it shows the message:

> No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.gov.mdic</groupId>
<artifactId>Offset</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Are you using the Maven Integration for Eclipse plugin? This would allow you to create a new Maven Project and a basic pom.xml would be generated for you.

Comment: create a new maven project (eclpise has this option) and start from there

Answer (score 3):

you have to add below lines before `<project>` tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
```